# Grant_type unsupported Request for Webservice connection

Tags: webservices, httprequest

I hope you are all doing well!

I currently try to develop a Listener on Carriotds which call a private webservice on Salesforce.

I use Basichttp request (which is in intern function of Carriots) and I need to POST on https://[...]/oauth2/token to get my token.

Here is my code :

```
def http = new BasicHttp()
def postHeader = ['Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']
def postBody = [
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: consumer_key,
        client_secret: consumer_secret,
        username: auth_username,
        password: auth_password
        ]
http.headers = postHeader;
http.verb ="POST";
http.payload =  JsonOutput.toJson(postBody);
http.url =sf_login_domain;
def res = http.send();
```

The SDK engine response is :
"  Details: 'Request error: 400 - {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}  '"

The grand-type shall be password but it seems that it doesn't work.

Did you ever ecounter this error?

Thank you,

Comment: What is the endpoint URL that you are using?

Comment: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token - i tried it with Postman and everything went well.